# Fast_bitrix24 Как правильно добавлять лидов?

Tags: python, битрикс24

Требуется добавлять лидов в битрикс24. Искал решения через API, и нашел варианты с помощью php скрипта и библиотеки python fast_bitrix24. Второй вариант более интересен в данном случае, т.к. я сам питонист, а лезть в php не особо хочется. Но не совсем понимаю как реализовать это. Так же хотел бы узнать еще варианты реализации этого процесса

```
b = fast_bitrix24.Bitrix('webhook')
with b.slow():
    results = b.call('crm.lead.add', tasks)
``
```

Comment: В телеге поищи группу `fast_bitrix24` там тебе скорей ответят

Answer (score 0):

Вдруг кому-то понадобится на будущее. Вот мой вариант решения:

```
tasks = {'fields': {
                'NAME': user.name,
                'UF_CRM_1637915163': user.city,
                'PHONE': [{"VALUE": user.phone, "VALUE_TYPE": "WORK"}]
b = fast_bitrix24.Bitrix('token')
            with b.slow():
                results = b.call('crm.lead.add', tasks)
```